# Need JavaScript function to run on textarea change

Tags: javascript, textarea

I have a `<td>` which I am turning into a textArea once I click on a button.  This works fine.  I also have a characterCounterEdit function which also works.  The only thing is the character counter only  works when I click the cursor in the textarea.  I want to trigger the character counter function soon as I jump into the editCommentToggle().

JavaScript:

```
function editCommentToggle( id )
{
    theRow = document.getElementById("id"+id);
    //user = theRow.cells[0].innerHTML;
    //date = theRow.cells[1].innerHTML;
    com = theRow.cells[2].innerText ;


    idx = 2;
    maxlength = 250;

        // Comment field
        cell = theRow.cells[idx];
        while( cell.childNodes.length > 0 ) cell.removeChild(cell.childNodes[0]);

        spanTag = document.createElement("span"); 
        spanTag.innerHTML = "You have <strong><span id='commentsCounter'>"+maxlength+"</span></strong> characters left.<br/>"; 
        cell.appendChild(spanTag);
        element = document.createElement("textarea");
        element.id="commentsTextArea-"+id;
        element.rows="3";
        element.value = com;
        element.style.width = "400px";
        element.maxLength = "250";
        element.onfocus = element.onkeydown = element.onkeyup = function(){return characterCounterEdit('commentsCounter', maxlength, this);}; 
        cell.appendChild(element);

        $(function()
                {
                    setTimeout("syncCommentTableSizes()",0);    <%-- Run after HTC code --%>
                });

    // Actions field
    cell = theRow.cells[++idx];
    while( cell.childNodes.length > 0 ) cell.removeChild(cell.childNodes[0]);

    link = document.createElement("a");
    link.href = 'javascript:saveComment('+id+')';

    element = document.createElement( "img" );
    element.className = "smallicon edit"; // check if we need this changed
    element.src="../images/icon_save.gif";
    element.border="0";
    element.alt = "Save";

    link.appendChild( element );

    cell.appendChild(link);
    cell.appendChild( document.createTextNode("  ") );

    link = document.createElement("a");
    link.href = 'javascript:cancelCommentEdit('+id+')';

    element = document.createElement( "img" );
    element.className = "smallicon delete"; // check if we need this changed
    element.src="../images/icon_cancel.gif";
    element.border="0";
    element.alt = "Cancel";

    link.appendChild(element);
    cell.appendChild(link);
}



function characterCounterEdit(id, maxLen, inputElement)
{
    spanId = document.getElementById(id);

    if (spanId)
    {
        // Update the counter the user sees.
        var whatIsLeft = maxLen - inputElement.value.length;

        if ( whatIsLeft < 0 ) whatIsLeft = 0;
        spanId.innerText = whatIsLeft;
    }

    // Restrict user from entering more than the maxlen.
    if ( inputElement.value.length > maxLen )
    {
        inputElement.value = inputElement.value.substring( 0, maxLen );
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok... So do that.... You already know what you want to do... Why ask here?

Comment: @diEcho seriously??

Comment: @Neal You are more knowledgeable than me. :)

Comment: @diEcho what about answering jQuery Questions then and leave the "javascript" questions alone? >.<

Comment: I dont understand how you could only help with jQuery and not javascript, surely you must understand javascript to be using jQery effectivley.

Comment: @Christoph : i m not good at javaScript. jQuery is much easier and have good documentation over the net. and after all its a javascript library.

Comment: @diEcho — Because loading a huge library for something simple is often overkill.

Comment: @Quentin : you are right Sir. but i dont think adding jQuery will slower the page with very large difference . its alwez  better to write 1 line rather than writing 100 lines of javascript code.

Comment: @diEcho — It can make significant differences, especially on a mobile connection (and on a mobile CPU).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not just call the required method inside the `editCommentToggle()`.  You seem to suggest this is what you want to do, but im not really sure why you haven't done it?

```
function editCommentToggle( id )
{
   //code to get the element here first as pointed out by a comment below.

   characterCounterEdit('commentsCounter', maxlength, element);

   .... rest of the function

}
```

Comment: I am doing that....`element.onfocus = element.onkeydown = element.onkeyup = function(){return characterCounterEdit('commentsCounter', maxlength, this);}; cell.appendChild(element);`

Comment: So you mean this function only fires onfocus and not onkeydown or onkeyup?

Comment: It only fires when I click into the textarea....NOT when i clicK on the button that calls editCommentToggle..How can it fire soon as editCommentToggle is called?

Comment: then instead of putting it on the onclick listeners etc just put the method call inside the editCommentToggle method.  I will edit my answer.

Comment: You need to pass in `element` after it has been created instead of `this`

Comment: Yes true, I hadn't even looked at the method call to be honest, but atleast this will give some indication of where to put it :)

Comment: Thats what I was thinking @jfrej..... so after I do this: `   element = document.createElement("textarea");`

Comment: Yeah that would be fine.  Sorry I hadn't looked properly at the method signature and forgot about `this` but the principle is still the same.  Just call the method wherever you need it rather than relying on the onclick and onfocus handlers.